# Blender 2.8 render wireframe select specific edges

Tags: wireframe

I would like to render a plank with a notch, as shown below, in wire-frame mode.

It should only show the outer edges, means I would like to **not** show the edges highlighted with the white arrows.

Is there such an option?

Also, related, why are some edges thicker than others?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hide the edges between faces that lay on the same plane, use a ***Decimate*** modifier above your *Wireframe* modifier.

Set it to ***Planar*** mode, and adjust the angle limit if needed.

[image]

The inconsistent line thickness is caused by the original mesh having been scaled up in the three dimensions with different scale factors. The mesh "remembers" these factors and applies them to the modifier results, making the wireframe stretched weirdly. To fix the problem, you must make the mesh "forget" that it has been stretched, and make the new scale permanent ("Apply" the transformation). To do so:

- select the object
- do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Scale*.

[image]

Comment: How did you make the notch? I used 3 loop cuts and one grab of the center edge to move it inwards. However, I then have 144 faces and the "decimate" modifier does not work as it should (I need to crank the angle to 90 and then some faces appear again).

Comment: A cube with 3 loop cuts (which is what also I did) is 18 faces, not 144! 144 is what the wireframe gets you, but note that the decimate modifier should go ABOVE the wireframe modifier! (See when I click the little up arrow in the gif)

Comment: Got it, that was the trick!

Answer (score 1):

> *if the question is about Wireframe view, rather than Wireframe modifiers, this (older) answer may be relevant*

There is an option to hide wireframe edges between faces that are at a small angle.

It's in the "Overlays options" menu of the 3D viewport, under *Geometry > Wireframe*:

[image]

<sup>I'm surprised as I would expect all the edges you've identified to disappear for values less than 1.0, yet two are remaining. [I'm checking whether this should be considered a bug](https://developer.blender.org/T72855).</sup>